# Analysis with a "nonpositive norm"

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, quadratic-forms

It is well-known that you can take a normed space and produce a metric on it given by $d(x, y) = |x - y|$.  This works well for things like Euclidean space.  However, I have seen people (notably people working with relativity) working with a "norm" that is nonpositive, that is, where you have vectors with $|v|^2 < 0$.  Using these "norms" stops the above creation of a metric space from working.  When I ask people how you can still do analysis on these spaces, they say to define the norm while pretending the space is Euclidean.

To make this idea more rigorous, I came up with this idea: Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $Q : V \to \mathbb R$ be a quadratic form.  If we have another positive-definite quadratic form $Q^+ : V \to \mathbb R$ such that $Q(v) \leq Q^+(v)$ for all $v \in V$, then we can define a metric on $V$ by using $Q^+$ as above.

This leads me to the following two questions:

1. Is this sufficient to do analysis on these spaces?  Will knowing that $Q(v) \leq Q^+(v)$ be enough to do anything we might want to do with $Q$ and operations related to it, such as its associated symmetric bilinear form?
2. Does such a $Q^+$ always exist?  The countably-infinite-dimensional case is easy through orthonormalization, but I'm not sure about the uncountably-infinite-dimensional case.  I know that there exist uncountably-infinite-dimensional spaces with no orthogonal basis, so I'm slightly worried that there is a counterexample to this conjecture.

Comment: in relativity, people only use the terms "norm" or "length" merely to evoke familiarity. Don't read too much into their abuse of language. What is relevant for doing analysis on these vector spaces is an appropriate topology. This topology is NOT induced in anyway by the quadratic form of the non-degenerate metric tensor, rather we fix one norm and define a topology accordingly. Why is this a perfectly reasonable thing to do? Because it is a standard theorem in analysis that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space induce the same topology ('equivalence of norms in finite-dimensions').

Comment: I feel like that still doesn't answer my questions, which are posed pretty precisely in my eyes: How do we know that that plays nicely with $Q$, and can we always do this even in the uncountably-infinite-dimensional case (I notice you only mention the finite-dimensional case)?

Comment: When you say no orthogonal basis, do you mean that there is no basis that is orthogonal w/r/t the inner product on the space or that there is no inner product and thus no concept of orthogonality?

Comment: I mean no orthogonal basis with respect to the symmetric bilinear form on the space.

Comment: Your first question was "is this sufficient to do analysis on these spaces", and my partial response was that analysis has to do with topology and $Q$ alone plays no (interesting) role in it. In finite-dimensions, we have a nice theorem. If you really wanted to, you could always consider the topology such that $Q$ ends up being continuous., but in almost every case of interest, this is not an interesting approach. In the infinite-dimensional case, I'm not sure, I haven't thought too hard about it, though my first idea is to see if the usual Zorn's lemma proof of maximality...

Comment: ... which works in the case of usual positive-definite inner products goes though in the case of an arbitrary non-degenerate bilinear form.